# Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop:: webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/pages/_document.js:304:1)

Tags: next.js

I am getting this warning:

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
    at Head (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/pages/_document.js:304:1)
    at html
    at Html (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/pages/_document.js:260:19)
    at MyDocument (webpack-internal:///./src/pages/_document.tsx:23:1)
```

It is difficult to debug because there's not information about where in my code could be causing this warning. I have looked through my code and did not see any lists with children without keys. I am guessing the warning may be internal/from a config file. I would appreciate thoughts on what could be causing it & how I might fix it.

When does it happen: When I'm on dev mode (using yarn dev) and I navigate to my localhost:3000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was in the custom src/pages/_document.tsx file

getInitialProps was returning

```
 return {
            ...initialProps,
            styles: [
              <>
                {initialProps.styles}
                {sheet.getStyleElement()}
              </>,
            ],
}
```

The solution was to provide a key to the fragments like this:

```
   return {
            ...initialProps,
            styles: [
              <React.Fragment key="someKey">
                {initialProps.styles}
                {sheet.getStyleElement()}
              </React.Fragment>,
            ],
}
```